# How do I make a specific tag invisible everywhere in my code?

Tags: reactjs

consider this code

```
class page1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const admin = false;

    return (
    <div>
    
        <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteEverything}>hello</button>

    </div>

    
 );
  }
}
```

Whenever the variable admin is false I don't want to see any button. I could do {admin ? button : null} but my issue with that is i would have to repeat admin several times in my actual code. Is there a one-liner that deactivates every button if admin is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable solution would be to create a custom component to wrap it:

```
const Button = ({show, ...props}) => show ? <button {...props} /> : null;
```

And use it:

```
<Button show={admin} onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

```
return (
    <div>
        {admin && (
            <>
                <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
                <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
                <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
                <button onClick={this.deleteEverything}>hello</button>
            </>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class page1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const admin = false;

    if (!admin) return <></>

    return (
    <div>
    
        <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteThis}>hello</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteEverything}>hello</button>

    </div>

    
 );
  }
}
```

you can try this